# How do I handle this Kind of Characters in php

Tags: php

I have a student number which has  the format  of '2/18/#ABC'   when i  try to enter in the database it is giving me  an error . How do i handle this 
Having the same student number ('2/18/11ABC' ) which we try  create a  unique barcode image with some classes which get interpreted as 
Unable to open '//main//sub-images//2/18/11ABC.jpg'  and gives us an error that it cannot find the image path. we know we were not able to handle this forward slashes . How can we handle  forward and backslashes for this situation .Do we need to use Regex or any?

Comment: This question seems to contain three different questions. Can you clarify the issues, show some code and quote the exact error messages you are getting?

Comment: @pekka:The Issues are  interlinked with each other on creation of this number in DB(2/18/#ABC).It gives us DB error  'Character in Cast Argument is not valid'. And we are using this number to create bar code image which doesnot have escaping for forward slash so we get the error "unable to open" error . So if we handle the way the student number is created by accepting foward slash and hashes(#) than we are good

Comment: I did not get part with image. Are you trying to use that student number as name of image file like **2/18/11ABC.jpg**? Could you post some examples like what you have and what you want at the end? That will help a lot. What exactly about handling forward and backslashes?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: we are trying to create the bar code image with the same number 2/18/11ABC.jpg. we were not able to create it . Iam thinking forward slashes  in the file name of image is making problem in opening. that is what regarding forward slashes and backward

Comment: I think you cant use slashes in filename? Try to replace them with dash for example, something like **2-18-11ABC.jpg**.

Comment: @Derby Please show some actual code. With the info you're giving, all people can do is guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stud_number = '2/18/11ABC';
$fname = str_replace('/', '_', $stud_number) . '.jpg';
echo $fname;
```

Output (safe filename):

**2_18_11ABC,jpg**

You can't use these characters `<`, `>`, `:`, `"`, `/`, `\`, `|`, `?`, `*` in file name.

Also, student number like this one **2/18/#ABC** can't be stored in database using numeric type of field! In numeric fields you can store **only numbers** in right number format (depends of numeric type you use) and in right range (also depends of numeric type you use).

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5:How do i handle the 2/18/11#ABC  '#' character entered in to the database

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5:I want it in the Database.

Comment: Is it mysql database you use and what is type of field you use to store numbers like this one with #?

Comment: you should use some textual data type to keep that kind of value (like text, char, varchar).

Comment: It is DB2  and it is numeric field

Comment: I don't know anything about DB2... but I know **YOU CAN'T STORE NUMBER IN THAT FORMAT** using numeric field. Why? Just because this is not number. It must be textual field.

Comment: @Derby this would be so much more productive if you actually showed some code, as now requested twice.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to replace # with 11?

if so you can do this by simply using

`str_replace('#','11',$mystring);` as long as you haven't got any other # symbols